# Openstreetmap Nominatim gives no output from nginx

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

trying to run Nominatim seems impossible.
I've followed instruction from [Nominatim installation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) and after trying to access url http://nominatim.mytest.com/ nginx says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2015:19:15:36 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
```

Not a single bit of ouput is there.
If I run from console php5 index.php there is a html output there.

Configuration for nginx is (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nominatim.mytest.com
):

```
 server {

    root /var/www/nominatim.mytest.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name nominatim.mytest.com;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$){
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
       if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
               return 404;
       }
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }
 }
```

Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       nominatim.mytest.com
```

Machine is:

```
 Ubuntu 14.10
 postgis 2.1.3+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1
 postgresql-9.4
 php5 5.5.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Addition of:

```
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

inside config file resolved issue.

Part of config file:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```